# Incrase bootstrap navbar input field width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've a twitter bootstrap 3 navbar with a input field. I want to increase the width of the input field. I've tried setting the `col` size but it doesn't work.

The html is quite long so please refer to the bootply.

http://www.bootply.com/LztVsLEz30

Comment: With CSS you can fine tune the width of input element. But if you OK with the simple, just use `size` attribute. Example `<input class="form-control" size="30">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pixel value to increase the width of the text field.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control search-input" name="query" id="query" placeholder="prof or mod name or mod code" style="500px;">
```

And use the percentage value for the responsive mode.

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
.navbar-form .form-control { 
    width: 100%; 
}}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you inspect element then you will find ".navbar-form" and ".form-control" has width as auto.

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-form .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

So to increase the width of your input you need to override its width as:

```
   <input type="text" class="form-control search-input" style="width:400px;" name="query" id="query" placeholder="prof or mod name or mod code">
```

or separately as

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-form .form-control {    
    width: 400px;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<div class="form-group" id="remote-prof">
  <input type="text" class="form-control search-input" name="query" id="query" placeholder="prof or mod name or mod code">
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.form-group {
  width: 225px;
}
div.form-group input.form-control {
  width: 220px;
}
```

[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/qdgjkboa/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go I have updated your link and [this is new](http://www.bootply.com/kDl5z5Vper) with width 400px;. Let me know if you didn't understand it